# ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. While updating the version 2.5.12 of Struts

Tags: java, logging, struts2, migration, log4j2

As per the requirement and for security purpose I am updating Struts project. Before the Struts version is 2.3.24 and now I am updating it to 2.5.12. I have downloaded all the required jar files of Struts and applied to project but I am getting the below error

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default
>   configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property
>   'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to
>   show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.

But I am not using any logger in my project. I have added all the dependency jar files and I am not using Maven, but added related libraries in lib folder. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Struts framework is using a logging framework log4j second version.

> #### [Struts 2.3 to 2.5 migration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration)
>
> Please be aware that the framework is using Log4j2 now as a main logging layer, the existing old logging layer is deprecated and will be removed soon. Log4j2 supports many different logging implementations, please check documentations for more details.

The file `log4j2.xml` is required to bootstrap the logging framework. But it's missing from the classpath. It's also missing from the Struts framework.

---

You should find some `log4j2.xml`, i.e. from the struts-showcase application or read a step 4 in this tutorial [How To Create A Struts 2 Web Application](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html)

> #### [Step 4 - Add Logging](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html#step-4---add-logging)
>
> To see what’s happening under the hood, the example application for this tutorial uses log4j2. You’ll need to add a dependency node for log4j2 to the pom:
>
> pom.xml log4j dependency node
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
>     <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
>     <version>2.8.2</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
>     <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
>     <version>2.8.2</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Using both log4j-core and log4j-api allows to use the latest version of Log4j2 without a clash with version provided by the framework. Setup a log4j2.xml configuration in the src/main/resources folder which contains the following
>
> **log4j2.xml**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Configuration>
>     <Appenders>
>         <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
>             <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
>         </Console>
>     </Appenders>
>     <Loggers>
>         <Logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2" level="debug"/>
>         <Logger name="org.apache.struts2" level="debug"/>
>         <Root level="warn">
>             <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
>         </Root>
>     </Loggers>
> </Configuration>
> ```
>
> Note the above log4j2 configuration specifies the console as the log target.

Comment: Sir i am not using Maven, and i have added libraries of both log4j-core 2.8.2 and log4j-api 2.8.2, still its not working.

Comment: Maven is essential for managing dependencies. You never know what library is required unless you resolve dependencies with Maven or any other tool.

Answer (score 0):

`No log4j2 configuration file found` means `log4j2.xml` configuration file is not in your classpath.

Check your project jar contains `log4j confuguration file` or not.

Otherwise you can set log4j confuguration file path as system property in your build script.

```
<sysproperty key="log4j.configurationFile" value="file:///${basedir}/src/log4j2.xml" />
```

Check https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for log4j configuration

Comment: But i am not using maven and i dont have any log4j2 configuration file.