# log4j2 not logging External jars/packages logs

Tags: spring, logging, struts2, log4j, log4j2

I've configured a logger in log4j2 properties file to write the log lines for org.springframework , org.apache.struts2 which are used in my application. But only the log lines of my main application package are only written in log file. Below is the configuration file :
#####################################################################

```
status = WARN
name= LoggingConfig


# Log files location
property.basePath = /all_logs/strutsAppLogs/

# Configure root logger
appenders=consoleAppender,strutsAppender

#Console logging to catalina.out
appender.consoleAppender.type = Console
appender.consoleAppender.name = LogToConsole
appender.consoleAppender.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.consoleAppender.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n


#RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appender.strutsAppender.type = RollingFile
appender.strutsAppender.name = Struts
appender.strutsAppender.fileName= ${basePath}/extensions.log
appender.strutsAppender.filePattern= ${basePath}/extensions_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.strutsAppender.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.strutsAppender.layout.pattern = %d{dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss} [%C.%M %L]  %-5p: %m%n
appender.strutsAppender.policies.type = Policies
# RollingFileAppender rotation policy
appender.strutsAppender.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.strutsAppender.policies.size.size = 10MB
appender.strutsAppender.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.strutsAppender.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.strutsAppender.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.strutsAppender.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.strutsAppender.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.strutsAppender.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.strutsAppender.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.strutsAppender.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
# Delete all files older than 30 days
appender.strutsAppender.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d


loggers=strutsLogger_1,strutsLogger_2

rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.appenderRefs=ar_consoleAppender,ar_strutsAppender
rootLogger.appenderRef.ar_consoleAppender.ref = LogToConsole
rootLogger.appenderRef.ar_strutsAppender.ref= Struts

logger.strutsLogger_1.name = org.springframework
logger.strutsLogger_1.level = info
logger.strutsLogger_1.additivity = false
logger.strutsLogger_1.appenderRef.strutsAppender.ref = Struts

logger.strutsLogger_2.name = org.apache.struts2
logger.strutsLogger_2.level = info
logger.strutsLogger_2.additivity = false
logger.strutsLogger_2.appenderRef.strutsAppender.ref = Struts
```

##################################################################################

```
Not able to identify the packages from logger.name
Fetching main application package from unknown location.
```

Have looked up a lot of sources and official documentation but no help.

Comment: For some reasons S2 debugging information is not included by default. In addition S2 is using their own logging framework Wich support both log4j and slf4j, the last is default. You can find more information on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45648287/573032) answer.